# What is meant by "Almost orthogonal"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, terminology

Figuratively speaking, when two quantum objects’ states are ‘almost orthogonal’, are they in some physical sense ‘almost blind’ to one another?

Comment: Maybe think about linear polarization (even though it's classical). 0/180 and 90/270 degrees are orthogonal, while 0/180 and 89/269 degrees are almost orthogonal, so that yes, the 89/269-degree light has a little bit of 0/180 degree light in it.

Comment: @JEB That sounds like it should be an answer

Comment: Seen in which reference?

Comment: @Qmechanic...No particular reference.  I'm a novice, no surprise.  I simply want to know the physicality of orthogonal and almost orthogonal states.  Eg: What does it mean physically for two electrons, say, to momentarily have their wave functions be orthogonal?  Classical physics seems to have no counterpart.